# Curl Scripts in /etc/hosts on Linux

Tags: linux, apache, shell, curl

Is it possible to add scripts (like curl) to /etc/hosts?  I am trying to set up a subdomain over ddns, and it's really hard to update my /etc//hosts file on the fly when my IP address updates without my knowledge.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is scripts that support Dynamic DNS that do this updating for you, no need to write anything by yourself, what DDNS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not. However, you will probably have some scripts that can be triggered when you get an IP address or something similar and those can be used to rewrite your `/etc/hosts`.